# Client (angular 2) authentication , passport google as provider in server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-oauth, passport.js, angular-cli

I've been looking a lot for an answer here.

I have a nodejs server with some REST endpoint. Each endpoint has `isLoggedIn` middleware so I can authenticate the user by it's email.

The client runs on port 4200 and the server runs on port 3113.

What I would like is basically to have my client redirect to Google's consent screen if not authenticated. Since the ports are different I get:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…d=604408607019-ha937stehe6s3nk7ea892rviihrq5n4s.apps.googleusercontent.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Now, what haven't I tried... :)

I tried using the CLI proxy feature (it's a webpack configuration) and to forward all `/api` requests to the server.

I have added headers to the server but then I realized that it's Google who's sending this error and not my server.

I saw lots of posts here that are related. The best solution that I've seen so far was to put a `login` button and just put the call to `auth` in `href`, because I cannot do ajax calls between domains.

Is this really the best solution? Isn't it any other way to authenticate from the client while the authentication code is running on the server?

I even added all the relevant ports for the api and the callback call to Google developer console.

BTW, all works well when a client is served from the same port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I have your solution. I just solved this myself and I stumbled upon your question when I was looking for a solution. You will not be able to call a `.http.get()` request from the google auth itself through Angular. What you're going to have to do is do a redirect `window.location.href = 'your-express-uri-here'` and then when you authenticate, you can create a new Express route, and get the user data from that route itself. for example you can call `.http.get('your-profile')` from angular and then in your express route have your route be `router.get('your-profile/', (req, res) =>{ res.send(req.user) }` This works, because with Passport you use a cookie and when you sign in you are authenticated already, and you have access to the data from the user. You don't need to have a GET request from the login to get the user data, just a GET request from your node app once you have already logged in using Google+Passport. For this to work, you do have to run Angular in proxy to your node app.